# inserting in mongo using express

Tags: mongodb, express

i am trying to put data in the mongodb using express but it is storing blank always ...also it is not printing any console logs :

the url i am hitting after starting the sever is

http://localhost:3000/posts?title=test&link=http://test.com

and it is showing the below output:

{"__v":0,"_id":"562717b064002b1c2e697b33","comments":[],"upvotes":0}

```
router.get('/posts', function(req, res, next) {
console.log('reached ere '+req);
 var post = new Post(req.body);

post.save(function(err, post){
if(err){ return next(err); }

res.json(post);
 });


 });
```

Post Scheme:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

 var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 title: String,
 link: String,
upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
 });

 mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your API as

> http://localhost:3000/posts?title=test&link=http://test.com

which will send `title` and `link` to server as query parameters and not body parameters. So your `req.body` in this case would be an empty object. That is the reason no data in being saved in your posts collection.

You have two options here:

1. Change your API to save `req.query` in posts collection which you can do as follows:

Replace

```
var post = new Post(req.body);
```

with

```
var post = new Post(req.query);
```

2. Pass `link` and `title` as body parameters instead of query parameters.